Movie about a man whose dreams alter reality
I've seen this movie in the 1990's.
The man is under the care of a psychiatrist.
The psychiatrist used a codeword antwerp in a hypnosis session.
The man dreams that there are no racial tensions in the world and everyone lives in harmony.

 When he wakes up, everyone in the world is gray.

The psychiatrist tries to manipulate the man.

“The Lathe of Heaven” (1980). And almost certainly a dupe of 1980s movie/series on PBS about a man & his psychiatrist in a post-apocalyptic world

https://musingsofamiddleagedgeek.blog/2021/04/27/effectively-dreaming-the-lathe-of-heaven-1980-into-reality/

@Valorum I checked the trailer for the movie on YouTube ... that is the movie ... please post an answer ... https://youtu.be/sbs3Y2HSoiw?si=tfLaoAr2b6SHvPA8

This is undoubtedly the 1980 movie The Lathe of Heaven, based on the 1971 book of the same name by Ursula K. LeGuin. From the Wikipedia entry:

In Portland, Oregon, in the near future, George Orr is charged with abuse of multiple prescription medications, which he was taking to keep himself from dreaming. Orr volunteers for psychiatric care to avoid prosecution, and is assigned to the care of licensed oneirologist William Haber. Orr's explanation of his drug abuse is incredible: He has known since age 17 that his dreams change reality, and tries to prevent himself from this "effective dreaming" because he fears their effects.
Haber initially considers Orr's fear as a delusional symptom of neurosis or psychosis, referring to him as "possibly an intelligent schizophrenic". The doctor puts Orr into a hypnotic trance while attached to the "Augmentor," a device he has invented for monitoring and enhancing, or augmenting, brainwaves during dreaming, to help with patient therapy. He encourages Orr to have an effective dream, recording his brain function all the while. The world changes slightly during this dream, and Haber realizes that Orr is telling the truth.
Haber begins to use Orr's effective dreams, first to create a prestigious, well-funded institute run by himself, then to attempt to solve various social problems. But these solutions unravel quickly: Haber suggests that Orr dream of an answer to overpopulation (resulting in a plague wiping out three-fourths of the human population), the end to all conflict on Earth (resulting in an alien invasion uniting mankind), and an end to racism (resulting in a world where everyone's skin is a uniform shade of gray).
Orr turns to lawyer Heather LeLache for help in getting out of his government-mandated treatments with Haber. LeLache doubts Orr's sanity, but agrees to help him, eventually becoming an ally. Orr falls in love with LeLache.
Only after several failed attempts to "make the world right" does Haber admit to Orr that he believes in Orr's power. Having used the Augmentor to record and analyze Orr's supremely complex dreaming brainwaves, Haber begins creating a machine that will allow him to have his own effective dreams, and remake reality directly.
As Haber continues to use Orr's dreams to create change in human society, Orr remembers a dream he experienced years ago, which is briefly portrayed at the opening of the film (and which, it turns out, is in fact reality): The world was destroyed in a nuclear war, and Orr was poisoned by radiation. In his dying moments, Orr dreamed a world where the war did not happen, resulting in the events of the film as we see them.
Haber enters the final version of his machine for directing dreams and learns this truth, driving him mad. Orr, who has joined him in the dream state, is able to stop Haber's nightmare before it destroys the world. The result is a reality that jumbles together elements of the different worlds that Haber created via Orr's dreams, but is relatively stable. Orr is heartbroken because the LeLache in this reality was never his close friend or lover.
As the film ends, Orr is working in an antique store run by an alien. LeLache comes in to browse. She has only a vague memory of him, but agrees to join him for lunch. They encounter Haber, in a wheelchair, on their way to lunch. Haber recognizes Orr, but cannot come out of his catatonia.

